# rails_admin cancan abilities not loaded first time

Tags: devise, cancan, rails-admin

I'm using RailsAdmin, this time with CanCan!
I've built my Ability Model and everything looks nice. Except for this problem:
When the user logs in for the very first time (I'm using Devise), for some reason the system is not loading the correct permissions. This leads to the unconvenient situation: the user can see more actions and entities the the actual permissions would normally grant. Any subsequent requests work fine and the correct permissions are loaded. Don't know what else I might add. Logs are not reporting anything relevant. Anyone experiencing something similar?

- rails 3.2.8
- rails_admin 0.4.4
- cancan 1.6.7
- devise 2.1.2